# Missing eMail in SPUser

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I have a small application that is making use of the SP-COM. I use the following code to get the current users email address:

```
ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
currentUser.retrieve();
currentUser.get_email()
```

Strange enough, for a couple of users the email addresse is not retrieved, even though the user has an email address when I look at the users settings-page. Looking at the json, that is coming back from the server, the email-address is also blank.

Any hints what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The `currentUser.retrieve()` is not meant to be used from code. [It is reserved for internal purposes.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee541006.aspx)

Also, are you using the `load()` and `executeQueryAsync()` methods which are required to fetch the data with the Client Object Model?

Try the following code:

```
    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    this._currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    context.load(this._currentUser);

    context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccessMethod),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailureMethod));

    function onSuccessMethod(sender, args) {

    alert(this._currentUser.get_email());

    }

    function onFailureMethod(sender, args) {

    alert(‘request failed ‘ + args.get_message() + ‘\n’ + args.get_stackTrace());

    }
```